# iOS - Change constraints in runtime works only first time

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have this code, that changle constraint based on visibility of element:

```
if (self.collectionView.isHidden){
     controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.collectionView.topAnchor).isActive = false
     controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view2.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
else {
     controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.collectionView.topAnchor).isActive = true
     controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view2.topAnchor).isActive = false
}
```

If I do this after `collectionView.isHidden` is set to true, it works. However, after I set `collectionView.isHidden = true` and call this code, it no longer works and `controller.view` is still attached to the top of view2.
There is also an height constraint attached to `collectionView` ant ist values is 50.

I also have tried manually setting `collectionView.frame.size.height = 50` (or some other default value) because without this, height of `collectionView.frame.size.height` is zero. But not works. I have tried call `collectionView.updateConstraints()`, but it has no effect either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I think you are setting a new constraint every time you call the function, you are not really removing the previous one.

Usually when I need this kind of logic I keep a reference to the constraint so that I can activate/deactivate it later, like this:

```
var controllerBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

Then I assign it like so:

```
controllerBottomAnchor = controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.collectionView.topAnchor)
controllerBottomAnchor?.isActive = true
```

Once I need to change it I just use the reference:

```
controllerBottomAnchor?.isActive = false
```

I typically use it for width and height anchors.

Comment: Thank you... It worked. You are right, I have chced and my solution was creating new constraints every time I have called the method. I thought that it is cached in some way and it will always return the same constraint, but no :)

Comment: Yep they're not cached unfortunately. Glad that you solved it